# Partition function microcanonical ensemble

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, partition-function

I was wondering if there is a way to understand the partition function for a microcanonical ensemble $$\mathcal Z(E)=\sum_{\text{microstate $i$ with energy $E$}} w_i$$

as a limit of the continuous case $$\mathcal Z(E)=\int \frac{\delta(E- H(q,p))}{ N! h^{3N}} dp dq .$$

So in what sense is the first sum a limit of the second integral?

I accept that the second one is also somehow a sum over states with equal energy, but the second expression seem to treat any collection of particles as indistinguishable.

Now I see a problem in two cases:

In Quantum Mechanics, I accept that the first one is a limit case of the second one, as fermions and bosons are per se indistinguishable, but what happens in classical mechanics?

1.) If I have n-gas particles of the same kind and they are distributed over a p-state system. Now, I permut them, without changing the number of particles in each state. Do I count this as an additional microstate in the first equation?

2.) If I have n-k gas particles of the first kind and k gas particles of a second kind and have a p-state system and permut them, without taking into account that they are different particles, is this an additional microstate?

I think if the answer to either case is yes, then the first equation CANNOT be a limit case of the second equation, as this one treats all permutations as a single state by the factor $N!$.

If anything is unclear, please let me know

Comment: Is the first expression supposed to be the quantum or classical partition function?  If it is the quantum partition function, then it's inappropriate to view it as a limit of the classical partition function.  The classical hamiltonian does not contain the information that is present in the quantum hamiltonian.

Comment: So far, we only covered classical statistical mechanics, so I thought that this first equation is also valid in the classical regime, is this wrong?

Comment: Well it depends on what you mean in that equation.  What is your definition of these microstates $i$?  In classical mechanics, a microstate is a point in phase space.  Since phase space is a manifold, it contains uncountably many points, so it's unclear how one would make sense of that sum.  Perhaps one might be referring to some discretization of phase space into cells, but that's not a very "classical" thing to do.

Comment: so you'd say that the first equation just does not apply in classical mechanics? - Actually, I don't know, which is why I wanted to ask this here ;-).

Comment: Basically yes because it's unclear what it even means in a classical context (again, what are the microstates $i$ to which you refer in that sum?).  If I were performing a classical statistical mechanics computation, I would use the integral expression.

Comment: well, a microstate is for us, really as you said, a point in phase space. so this would be a counting of states in phase space (I mean there are certainly many problems with this equation(i.e. it gives infinity, iy there are more than finitely many points in phase space). but in the quantum regime, you would avoid double counting, as particles are per se indistinguishable when you would use that sum?